# Activate ip forwarding - persistent - ubuntu core

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'm trying to activate ip forwarding at boot-time on my ubuntu core image. I can run the command:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

It works. Then I reboot the machine, the forwarding is gone.
On ubuntu server I can update the file /etc/sysctl.conf .

This file is "read only" in ubuntu-core.

What is the "prefered" way to add ip forwarding in ubuntu core?

// Micke

Answer (score 2):

If you have superuser permissions you can edit any file with any permissions. Open `/etc/sysctl.conf` with your favourite editor (`vi`, `nano` etc)  find string **#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1**, remove the leading **#** symbol, save the changes. And run `sudo sysctl -p`.

Also, you can reboot your machine to make sure the changes are in place.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration files in `/etc/sysctl.d/` are available for read-write on recent Ubuntu Core.

On Ubuntu Core 18, I just tested adding a line here - `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.d/10-snapd-network.conf` :

```
# manually adding ip forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

-> that does the trick.

Note:
It would probably be neater to be able to `snap set system network.ipv4-ip-forward=true`, like one can for example `snap set system network.ipv6-disable=true`

But that doesn't seem to be possible at the moment.